# Displacement map exporting trouble

Tags: uv, export, displacement, depth-map, zbrush

So, following tutorial by creating Displacement map (through ProjectAll) and then exporting it with the model to Blender (through Multi Map Exporter plugin (UDIM format) [image]

and GoB addon) then applying Displace modifier [image: Displace],

I ran into some problems.

*It works perfectly in Zbrush*

[image: level 1 subdiv]

[image: level 4 subdiv]

But in Blender this thing happens:

[image][image]

Here's my settings:

[image]

Please help!! I'm stuck because of this problem and I can't solve it
Thank you in advance!!!!
P.S. the model is standard size (Deformation -> Unify in Zbrush)

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to be setting your displace modifier to displace in local Z axis.  It's more likely that you want it to displace in the normal.  But it depends on what kind of displacement map you're using.  If it has color (3 channel?), you might want to be using RGB to XYZ displacement instead.

Comment: My bad, posted wrong picture, but the result is the same even with normal displacement. Without 3 channels (as the model doesnt have colors)  model with the modifier changed but in a stange way: some parts are the same, others are inflated